# Does a constructor / destructor have to have code, or is the function enough?

Tags: c++

So if I have a class

```
class Transaction {

int no;
char dollar;

public:

    Transaction();
    ~Transaction();
}
```

And in my constructor / destructor

```
Transaction::Transaction {
    cout << "Entering constructor" << endl;
}

Transaction::~Transaction {
    cout << "Leaving program" << endl;
}
```

is that code enough for my constructor and destructor to work? Will it set the data members in my class to a safe state even though I declare nothing in my constructor?

Comment: Those members will, in this case, remain uninitialized regardless of whether you include that constructor or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class has only simple data members, so you don't even need (or should want) a destructor.

You should, however, initialize your data members in the constructor:

```
Transaction::Transaction()
  : no(0), dollar('$') {
    cout << "Entering constructor" << endl;
}
```

Otherwise, they will not be initialized, and may contain random values (C++ doesn't guarantee initialization of primitive non-static members to any particular value if you don't initialize them in the constructor). This can be particularly insidious if you have pointer members.

Comment: The guidance is good, but the description of C++ behavior is not precisely correct.

Comment: Yeah...I still haven't learned enough C++11. (I am hampered by the fact that I have to frequently work with code that doesn't compile in C++11 mode :( ). I believe my description is correct for C++03?

Comment: The rule that static storage variables and their members get zero-initialized isn't new.  What you said is correct for variables with automatic or dynamic duration.

Comment: Added "non-static" for clarity; hope that helps. (I'm used to colloquially referring to "member" in the non-static sense, but the spec doesn't use that terminology).

Comment: Well, static data members do have static storage duration, but the rule is a lot more general; it catches global variables and function-static variables as well.

Comment: You forgot your parentheses between `Transaction`.

Answer (score 5):

Each subobject will be default initialized, if you provide a constructor without specifying initializers for said subobject.

Section 8.5 of the Standard provides that:

> If no initializer is speciﬁed for an object, the object is default-initialized; if no initialization is performed, an object with automatic or dynamic storage duration has indeterminate value. [ Note: Objects with static or thread storage duration are zero-initialized, see 3.6.2. — end note ]

and that

> To *default-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
>
> - if `T` is a (possibly *cv-qualified*) class type, the default constructor for `T` is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
> - if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
> - otherwise, no initialization is performed.
>
> If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a const-qualiﬁed type `T`, `T` shall be a class type with a user-provided default constructor.

There are two ways to initialize subobjects: in the *ctor-initializer-list*, and in a *brace-or-equal-initializer* in the member declaration (for non-static members the latter is new in C++11).

In practice, this means that when you don't provide an initializer, variables of primitive type, such as `int` and `char`, retain whatever value was left in memory previously.  In most cases it's extremely hard to predict what value that will be, but you should be aware that it could be a leftover sensitive datum such as a password.

In the case of initialization of variables of static storage duration (such as objects at namespace scope and their members), the Standard further provides (same section) that:

> Every object of static storage duration is zero-initialized at program startup before any other initialization takes place.

This is subtly different from what happens during *value-initialization* if you did not define a constructor:

> To value-initialize an object of type `T` means:
>
> - if `T` is a (possibly *cv-qualified*) class type with a user-provided constructor, then the
>     default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
> - if `T` is a (possibly *cv-qualified*) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object is zero-initialized and, if `T`’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is called.
> - if `T` is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
> - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

but the effect is the same -- primitive members are set to zero and all others have their zero-argument constructor invoked.

nneonneo's advice to initialize all members explicitly is good, since having zero-initialization only for variables of static storage duration often leads to difficult-to-find bugs.  But it's perfectly viable to use the *brace-or-equal-initializer* technique:

```
class Transaction
{
    int no = 0;
    char dollar = 0;
public:

    Transaction();
    ~Transaction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not have to have code. In fact, in most languages you can leave it out and it will construct the class properly.

Comment: ...in most languages? This is C++.

Comment: @Christian I think the question is actually different. It seems to ask whether explicit member intialization is required inside the constructor definition, not if the constructor itself is necessary.

Comment: ah, I see. a bit confused by the wording